# Image is not displayed in print preview

Tags: javascript, html, printjs

I am learning print.js, but I am having trouble printing the image. I tried to called printJS but the image is not displayed in the print preview.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://printjs-4de6.kxcdn.com/print.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://printjs-4de6.kxcdn.com/print.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <image src="test-01.jpg"/>
    <button type="button" onclick="printJS('test-01.jpg','image')">
        Print
     </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://jsbin.com/juhanizobu/1/edit?html,js,output — I can't reproduce the problem, it works fine when I test it.

Comment: @ Quentin  it didn't work for local image files

Comment: @潘夏开 then it could be a problem with your image path

Comment: @潘夏开Can you try running your app through something like `http-server` and then try to print? Cheers

Comment: @Quentin cat.jpg:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/%E2%80%AA/cat.jpg 404 (Not Found)
I got the error just now, i call decodeURI() to decode the URL andI got the result is http://127.0.0.1:5500/cat.jpg

Comment: @Quentin yes,when I used http as url ,it works